# QObject-ы внутри внутри QThread

Tags: c++, qt

Возможно ли средствами QT как-то узнать какие QObject-ы находяться внутри QThread-а ?

Comment: зависит от реализации

Comment: Эти объекты помещены в поток методом `QObject::moveToThread` или являются полями класса-наследника `QThread`?

Comment: Эти объекты помещены в поток методом QObject::moveToThread.

Я так понимаю, если они являются полями класса-наследника, то можно их найти с помощью QThread::children, да ?

Comment: Если объекты помещены в поток методом `QObject::moveToThread`, то найти их нельзя. Если являются полями наследника `QThread`, то можно через `QMetaObject`, но это сложно. Метод `QObject::children` возвращает вектор объектов, которые являются по дочерними по отношению к родительскому объекту: либо родительский объект был указан в конструкторе `QObject::QObject(QObject parent = 0)`, либо был установлен методом `QObject::setParent`.